# Getting Value from html form with the same name attribute under Loop

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a form which displays multiple rows from database with 4 columns.  From these record I need to write a new value in 4th column and update database record. But whenever I try, only First Row  value can be updated/read. But not the other rows!! This can be due to the same "name=redirection" as it is given to each from "for loop". So, how can I get the values from other rows too??

```
for (int i=0; i<domains.size(); i++) {
domainprops = (String[]) domains.get(i);   
%>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" class="tableview" width="100%">
<td width="150"><input type="text"  id="domains" name="domains" value="<%=domainprops[0]%>"></td>
<td width="160"><input type="text"  name="defaulturl" value="<%=domainprops[1]%>" size="30"></td>
<td width="160"><input type="text"  name="redirecturl" value="<%=domainprops[2]%>" size="30"></td>

<td width="160"> <input type="text" id="redirection" name="redirection"></td>

<td align="right"><a href="javascript:win2('recordUpdate.jsp?domains=<%=domainprops[0]%>
')">[Update]</a></td>

    </tr>
 </table>

<% } %>
```

Javascript Code :

```
function win2(urlPath) {
    var winl = (screen.width-200)/2;
    var wint = (screen.height-100)/2;
    var settings = 'height=100,width=200,directories=no,resizable=no,status=no,scrollbars=no,menubar=no,location=no,top=' + wint + ',left=' + winl;

    var changeurls=document.getElementById("redirection").value;
    urlPath+='&rdirect='+changeurls
    editWin.focus();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Please read the answer referring to having multiple elements with the same ID. You should not be using multiple of the same ID.

You could use Javascript to iterate over redirection form elements.

```
function loopThroughRedirection(form) {
    var result = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
        if (form.elements[i].name == 'redirection') {
            // Do something to retrieve the value of redirection
            result += form.elements[i].value
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: @winglerw28.. Thanks. I used array but it gives me the result "undefiend".  My code is below
   var arr = new Array(); 
         var obj="";
         arr = document.getElementsByName('redirection'); 
         for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
                obj = document.getElementsByName('redirection').item(i); 
               if(!(obj==null || obj==''))
                   break;
                   
            } 
document.write("ChangeURL::>> " +obj.value);

Comment: EDIT: Read the answer above mine - I had not realized you were using multiple IDs of the same name.

Comment: @winglerw28.. Thanks mate!! Your Idea guided me to the solution and easier to understand the bug I made... !! cheers,

Answer (score 3):

An ID in the DOM is supposed to be unique. If any element in the DOM has an ID, it should not be shared by any other element.

What I would suggest doing is appending your loop counter on to the end of the ID. This will ensure that every element you create in the DOM has its own unique ID.

```
for (int i=0; i<domains.size(); i++) {
domainprops = (String[]) domains.get(i);   

...
<input type="text" id="domains_<%= i %>" name="domains" value="<%=domainprops[0]%>">
...
<input type="text" id="redirection_<%= i %>" name="redirection"></td>



</tr>
</table>

}
```

Next, pass the loop counter to the win2 function call:

```
<td align="right"><a href="javascript:win2('recordUpdate.jsp?domains=<%=domainprops[0]%>
', <%= i %>)">[Update]</a></td>
```

Finally, adjust the function itself...

```
function win2(urlPath, loopID) {
...
    var changeurls=document.getElementById("redirection_" + loopID).value;
    urlPath+='&rdirect='+changeurls
...
}
```

Comment: @user2062653... Thanks a lot.. I think I am very close to the answer. It did show me the loopID...   But now only one problem is.. When I type a new data on redirection  and click on update  .. it shows me the following erro..  "document.getElementByID(...) is null..     Why it is returning null value??